# Overloading lexical_Cast with a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, lexical-cast

I'm trying to extend lexical_cast to handle string->cv::Point conversions, with code like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

namespace boost {
  template<>
    cv::Point2f lexical_cast(const std::string &str) {
      std::vector<std::string> parts;
      boost::split(parts, str, boost::is_any_of(","));
      cv::Point2f R;
      R.x = boost::lexical_cast<float>(parts[0]);
      R.y = boost::lexical_cast<float>(parts[1]);
      return R;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  auto p = boost::lexical_cast<cv::Point2f>(std::string("1,2"));
  std::cout << "p = " << p << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And it works great.. However, `cv::Point2f` is actually `cv::Point_<T>` where T can be int, float, double, etc.  I can't find anyway to expose that templated arg to the lexical_cast, so that I can have a single lexical_cast function that can handle all `cv::Point_<T>` types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
struct point_type {};

template <typename T>
struct point_type<cv::Point_<T>> { using type = T; };

namespace boost {
  template <typename T, typename U = typename point_type<T>::type>
    T lexical_cast(const std::string &str)
    {
      std::vector<std::string> parts;
      boost::split(parts, str, boost::is_any_of(","));
      T R;
      R.x = boost::lexical_cast<U>(parts[0]);
      R.y = boost::lexical_cast<U>(parts[1]);
      return R;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f123525d0c6c4eea)

---

The previous, a little more complicated solution, if you don't like this implicit second template parameter of `lexical_cast`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_point : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_point<cv::Point_<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct point_type;

template <typename T>
struct point_type<cv::Point_<T>> { using type = T; };

namespace boost {
  template <typename T>
    auto lexical_cast(const std::string &str)
      -> typename std::enable_if<is_point<T>::value, T>::type
    {
      std::vector<std::string> parts;
      boost::split(parts, str, boost::is_any_of(","));
      using U = typename point_type<T>::type;
      T R;
      R.x = boost::lexical_cast<U>(parts[0]);
      R.y = boost::lexical_cast<U>(parts[1]);
      return R;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf988b0625dfe2e7)

Comment: @Yeraze I simplified it a little

Comment: How could this be extended for other tpyes? (e.g. cv::Point3_, cv::Size, etc).  I tried making 2 copies of this, one around cv::Point_ and one around cv::Point3_, and it fails to compile with an error around redefinition of the lexical_Cast function (even with is_point or point_type changed)

Comment: @Yeraze in separate function? in the same function? what is `cv::Size`? how exactly do you see it?

Comment: Ah, i got it.. Had to specialize the return type (instead of T, I made it cv::Point_<U>, or whatever, and that was enough to distinguish it).